# Trying to append an integer from a file with nothing in it throws an error

Tags: python, file, append

```
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cs.append(int(line))
```

However if there is nothing in the text file, it will not allow the rest of my code to run, even though later in the program, I write integers into the text file. This is the code I use to write integers into the text file:

```
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt', 'w') as f:
for value in cs:
    f.write('{}\n'.format(value))
```

And here is the error I am recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\League Tracker no api.py", line 8, in <module>
        cs.append(int(line))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is due to the fact that "empty" lines have only whitespace on them. In your case, they have a tailing newline character (`\n`). Stripping this away would solve your problem... kinda. You'd still have the problem of an empty string not being a valid number. Thus, simply skip the empty lines as follows, and you should be fine!

```
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        cs.append(int(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a list comprehension :

```
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    cs = [int(l.strip()) for l in f if l.strip()]
```

Or, if `cs` already contains some values that you wish to keep:

```
cs = [1, 2, 3]
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    cs.extend(int(l.strip()) for l in f if l.strip())
```

Note that neither of these handles potential errors that might occur if there is non-numeric data in the input. A more robust way to to use `try...except`:

```
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    try:
        cs = [int(l.strip()) for l in f if l.strip()]
    except ValueError, exc:
        print exc
```

Finally, if you want to ignore non-numeric values in your input you need to use a standard for loop:

```
cs = []
with open('leaguestatlogcs.txt') as f:
    for n, l in enumerate(f, 1):
        try:
            cs.append(int(l.strip()))
        except ValueError, exc:
            print "Skipping line %d due to: %s" % (n, exc)
```